# SOAP UI - Transferring an ID from JSON response URL to be used in another step

Tags: json, soap, groovy

I have a request, which returns JSON response in the below format:

{"href": "http://example.com/abc/api/heards/41172e5c-75a6-4844-a745-02e1021632bb"}

I want to parse the UUID at the end of the above URL and use it in a request in the next step. So, for e.g. the next request should look like this:

http://pqr.com/qwertyy/41172e5c-75a6-4844-a745-02e1021632bb

How can I do this in SOAP UI/Ready API?

Answer (score 0):

Since the UUID is at the end of the URL, you can

1. `split()` the String using **/** as the delimiter
2. grab the last item in the List

Here's an example:

```
def uuid = "http://example.com/abc/api/heards/41172e5c-75a6-4844-a745-02e1021632bb".split('/')[-1]
```